# Why doesnt firefox redirect after printing?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, printing, hyperlink

First of all, this is a new problem which happens since a few weeks. Currently I'm using FF Version 37.

On multiple sites of our Intranet we use links, that look like this

```
<a href='some_page.php' onclick='window.print()'>Print</a>
```

The printing part works fine and normally after the printing is done, the page changes its location. This doesn't happen anymore. We found a temporary workaround, that redirects the page via JavaScript after a timeout of a few seconds. It is hard to find a timeout, that isn't too long for a good user experience and isn't too short so that the redirect doesn't fire.

Does anyone know a solution for this, except rolling back to an older version of Firefox or changing the browser entirely?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
<a href='some_page.php' onclick='doPrint(); return false;'>Print</a>

function doPrint() {
   window.print();            
   document.location.href = "some_page.php"; 
}
```

Comment: Like I said. This only works if there is a timeout before the document.location

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug if it was redirecting for you before, I'd suggest logging a ticket with Firefox with examples